# getting the value from PHP variable into html

Tags: php, html, css, web

I am just new to PHP.Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 $pidd="123456";
 ?>

 <form name="Form1" id="user-info" action='trackit.php' method="POST">

 <input type="hidden" name="pidd" id="pidd" value='<?php=$pidd?>'/>

 <input name="Re-Activate My Account"  value=" Re-Activate My Account"  type="submit"   />
 </form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

I am trying to access the value of pidd and writing it to a file here into tracking.php

```
<?php
$redirect = $_POST["pidd"];
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $redirect;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//Redirect the user to their intended location
header('Location: index.html');
?>
```

but the problem i am facing is, it is not getting the value of pidd as 123456, its just writing it as a string as it is  "?php=$pidd?". Can anyone please help me to figure out where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just figured out the problem was my file was .html and i changed it to .php, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved like that:

```
<?php echo $ppid; ?>
```

Or

```
<?= $ppid; ?>
```